# Is my HVAC condenser fan motor wired incorrectly?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

My condenser fan motor stopped working and I noticed black scorched marks on the Defrost Control Board where the fan connection is (near DF2 and the relay that is used to run the fan). The HVAC condenser is a Goodman CPLJ42-1.

The fan side of the capacitor looked good. A friend took the line connected to DF2 of the fan and put on the common side of the capacitor and I started to smell smoke and burning smell from the fan. Later, I noticed the purple or the common wire of the fan connected to DF2 and the black or run wire of the fan connected to the common of the capacitor.

I was wondering is there any issue with connecting the run wire to the common side of the capacitor or the common wire to the line side of the contactor. Could this wiring damage the fan motor or is it relatively harmless?

Comment: What does your wiring diagram for the condenser show? It should be inside the unit or you can get one online.

Comment: Burning and smoke smell after changes wires around is usually an "Oh Darn" moment.  Black scorch marks also usually means something went poof.

Comment: Its a little hard to look through the one that is attached to the metal door of the condenser service bay but even if I found it I wouldn't be able to understand it immediately. Its just the typical three wire fan motor with a start, run, common wire. It's this one: https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Fan-Motor/0131M00847S/4959196 Even without a wiring diagram, start is on the fan side of the cap. The other two is where I'm confused. The common should have been on the C of the cap but it was on the DF2 of the control board.